# Cannot fix start manual transfer runs method for bigquery_datatransfer_v1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to run a scheduled query only when a table updates in big query. For this I am trying to make this python code to work in cloud functions, but it is giving me error. Would highly appreciate any help.

I am running this python code :

```
import time
from google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2 import Timestamp
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer_v1

def runQuery (parent,requested_run_time):
    client = bigquery_datatransfer_v1.DataTransferServiceClient()
    projectid = '629586xxxx' # Enter your projectID here
    transferid = '60cc15f8-xxxx-xxxx-8ba2-xxxxx41bc'  # Enter your transferId here
    parent = client.transfer_config_path(projectid, transferid)
    start_time = Timestamp(seconds=int(time.time() + 10))
    response = client.start_manual_transfer_runs(parent, requested_run_time=start_time)
    print(response)
```

I get this error

```
start_manual_transfer_runs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'requested_run_time'
```

Comment: hi @usman rafi, is this resolved? I was wondering how are you triggering your cloud function because you want to run a scheduled query only when a table updates in big query. Are you using pub sub event ?

Answer (score 0):

I created doing this using cloud function and it worked for me.

```
import time
from google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2 import Timestamp 
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer_v1

def runQuery(parent, requested_run_time):
    client = bigquery_datatransfer_v1.DataTransferServiceClient()
    PROJECT_ID = 'graphical-reach-285218'
    TRANSFER_CONFIG_ID = '61adfc39-0000-206b-a7b0-089e08324288'
    parent = client.project_transfer_config_path(PROJECT_ID, TRANSFER_CONFIG_ID)
    start_time = bigquery_datatransfer_v1.types.Timestamp(seconds=int(time.time() + 10))
    response = client.start_manual_transfer_runs(parent, requested_run_time=start_time)
    print(parent)
    print(response)
```

Replace with your project id and transfer config id. The above code will go in main.py and in requirements.txt , please keep

```
google-cloud-bigquery-datatransfer==1
```